# Is there always a relation between different numbers?

Tags: number-theory

I am studying number theory and suddenly this question came to my mind.

Suppose we have these ten numbers 454, 678, 123, 548, 908, 879, 347, 873, 309, 568. Is there any relation between these numbers? If yes, will there always be any sort of relation between any type of different numbers?(Even if it is hidden and we don't know it yet).

If yes, then how to find the relation between different numbers? And I am wondering is there a way to find relation between different numbers using computation(I guess computational number theory)?

Comment: Langrage interpolation polynomial will always pass through any set of numbers. So there is always a contrived relation !

Comment: @Shailesh: what relation does the Lagrange polynomial induce ??

Comment: There is a polynomial $f(x)$ such that $f(1)=454$, $f(2)=678$, etc. This polynomial must be at least degree nine (one fewer than the number of points it must pass through). It's a good exercise to prove this. Start by showing that there is a polynomial $f_n(x)$ such that $f_n(x)=1$ and $f_m(x)=0$ for all $1\le m\le 10$ and $m\ne n$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger You mean that the polynomial can always be chosen of degree at most $9$. It could certainly have smaller degree in some cases.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft You're right. My bad.

Comment: They sum to $5687$. Does this count as a "relation"?

Comment: @Shailesh: I wouldn't really call that a relation between the numbers, rather a way to generate them. It is much stronger than a single relation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a contrived relation:

> They are all elements of the set:
>   $$\{454,678,123,548,908,\\879,347,873,309,568\}$$

If you care about the order, you can talk about ordered tuples rather than sets.

Lagrange interpolation might be more satisfying, but it's also kind of contrived.

Answer (score 1):

If you put no constraint on what a relation is, the answer is trivially that there are as many relations as you like.

Take any function of $n$ arguments, let $F$, and evaluate it for the given numbers, yielding a value $v$. Then

$$F(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,\cdots)=v$$ is a relation.

For example,

$$454+ 678+ 123+ 548+ 908+ 879+ 347+ 873+ 309+ 568=5687.$$

You may have in mind some "compact" or "anthropomorphic" or "interesting" or "semantically meaningful" or "elegant" or "parsimonious" idea of a relation. This needs to be formalized.

---

Interesting (and terribly difficult) classes of relations could be "equality of two multilinear/polynomial/rational expressions formed using these constants once and only once".

For two numbers, the only possibility is
$$a=b.$$
For three numbers, one of
$$a+b=c,\ ab=c,\ a^b=c$$ or equivalents.

For four,
$$a+b+c=d,\ a+b=c+d,\ ab+c=d,\ ab=c+d,\ ab=cd,\ abc=d,\ \frac ab+c=d,\\a^b+c=d,\ \cdots$$

All of these Diophantine equations have a solution set, the union of which may or not span the whole of $\mathbb N^n$.

---

If I am right, in none of these models do
$$\color{red}{1,3,5}$$ have a relation.

And there are no two-parameter relations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's always a relation even if the relation may not be obvious. The relations between your numbers are that they're all in the sequence $454, 678, 123, 548, 908, 879, 347, 873, 309, 568$.

As for determining the relation it will not be unique. We have for example the problem of determine the next number in a sequence which is an ambiguous problem. Take for example the sequence $2, 3, 5$ what is the next number? Is it $7$ or $8$? That's depends, the sequence is the first primes, but they are also Fibonacci numbers - two different relations between them. In fact since there's always a relation there's also a relation that would make the next number $42$ (since there's a relation between the numbers $2, 3, 5, 42$ as well).